# What does "chance to dismember" mean?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Well, obviously it means I have a higher chance of dismembering enemies. But I have no idea what this actually does in terms of gameplay. I have various items that increase my chance to dismember, but no idea if that effect is worth it.

What exactly does dismembering do in this game, what effect has it on enemies?

Comment: All it does is give you an additional chance upon a kill to dismember the enemy. If you watch when you kill people you do not always dismember them, there is a base chance for that to happen. The trophy that gives you 10% more chance to dismember on a kill. It has no effect on gameplay or enemies other than a different kill scene. I have seen heads come off, people cut in half, arms, legs, chest slashed diagonal, and more.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that when you are fighting an enemy, particular human ones, there's a chance that one of your fast/strong attacks will activate a killing animation, which instantly kills the enemy, even if they are at high health, which makes it particularly useful.

So dismembering is essentially an insta-kill, but I think I mostly see it occur on humans, not as much on monsters, if at all.

Comment: It seems to work quite well on Drowners in my experience, but that's the only monster type I've been able to 'execute' in this way.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, that's one. Basically, dismemberment will activate on any monsters that have limbs positioned similarly to humans. Drowners is definitely one.

Comment: So most Necrophages? And maybe a few others like Nekkers and such

Comment: Dismembering is by no means an insta-kill. there are insta-kills in the game and it is by effect of weapons, though extremely rare (50 hours played and I have seen one). Dismembering occurs on a kill and a kill only, does not have an effect of an instant kill. The scenes you speak of are based of off your current attack being capable of killing the opponent out right with that attack, and if there are not enemies in the middle of attacking you else where.

Comment: @Dupree3 I’m afraid you are wrong. Launch Axii on a human enemy with full health and do a heavy attack. Quite often you will insta-kill it. In my experience, it works best when you do it on the last enemy of the fight

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the internet does not have a consensus on this issue.  That having been said, my experience has been as @Dupree3's - I've yet (in over 70 hours of play) been able to insta-kill anything using this ability.  While it can be satisfying to watch the clever animation of cutting someone in half in random angles, particularly for certain humans (Bandits that prey on Peasants, in particular), I have not insta-killed anything with a dismemberment with substantially more health left than a critical could also take down, while carrying the Griffin Head.

Comment: I write here the same I wrote above to Dupree. Dismember DO insta-kill enemies even with full health.  Launch Axii on a human enemy with full health and do a heavy attack. Quite often you will insta-kill it. In my experience, it works best when you do it on the last enemy of the fight